# Can't change public variables on a script attached to a gameobject. Values are restored upon play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Here is my first question. Haven't been able to find anything on the topic.

I want to create an editor script that changes a number of public bools in a script that is attached to a GameObject.

I have this script attached to a GameObject. The GameObject is a prefab:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScriptWithPublicBools : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool b1;
    public bool b2;
}
```

And here is my editor script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class EditorHelper : ScriptableObject
{
    [MenuItem("Trace/Trace")]
    public static void trace()
    {
        foreach (GameObject g in Selection.gameObjects)
        {
            ScriptWithPublicBools tb = g.GetComponent<ScriptWithPublicBools>();

            if (tb)
            {
                tb.b1 = false;
                tb.b2 = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The scripts are working fine and the bools on the gameobject is set correctly in the editor. But when I press the PLAY button the values of the two bool switches back the  values they were before the script was applied.

It does not matter what the values of the prefab is, the values are just restored to the values before applying the editor script.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

If I apply the editor script, save the scene as a new scene, and open the newly created scene the values are also wrong.

BUT, if the GameObject is not a prefab all works perfectly, and the values keep their values given by the editor script, even after initiating play mode.

So the problem is only present when using prefabs.

Comment: +1 interesting one and welcome to SO.  _(The GameObject is a prefab)_: A GameObject within the scene is from my understanding an instance of a prefab but not the prefab itself. Do I understand you right that the changes are visible in this instance but aren't applied to the prefab itself?

Comment: Yes, you have understood me correctly. And you are correct that the GameObject in my scene is an instance of a prefab. The values that are being set by the editor script are only applied and visible on the GameObject within the scene – they are not applied to the prefab. But when I press the PLAY button or save the scene and reopen, the values are not saved, instead they are restored to the values before applying the editor script. This does not happen if I break the prefab instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `EditorUtility.SetDirty (tb);` after all changes are done, see [EditorUtility.SetDirty](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) for more information on this.

In case you need to change the prefab itself, have a look at [PrefabUtility](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.html)